# Matlab How to find mutual numbers in 2 different vectors and replace them?

Tags: matlab

Help!

How to find mutual numbers in 2 different vectors and replace them?

I have this situation:

```
2016    2059    43
2362    2450    88
2451    2474    25
2475    2684    36
3301    3332    31
```

I would like to get start and end when the colum 1 is different from the second column by 1 or zero and the column number 3 has to add the value as in the following example. im sorry for my bad explanation guys.

Here is the output that i would like to get

```
2016    2059    43
2362    2684    149
3301    3332    31
```

Comment: Are the first 2 columns sorted? and also is the 2nd column bigger than the first?

Comment: You should explain better which numbers of column 3 get added

Comment: @LuisMendo I think he wants a "traceback" Checking if a value in column 2 exists also in column 1. If so overwrite it with the corresponding column 2 value and add the 2 corresponding column 3 values. In his given example the "first new" column 2 value of `2362` would have been `2474`. So he added `88+25`. Then he saw that the "first new" column 2 value exists in column 1 again. So he overwrites again. Resulting in `[2362 2684 88+25+36=149]` as output

Comment: @TheMinion Thanks. Yes, that's the most likely conclusion from the example. But I would rather have that clarified before attempting an answer

Comment: Wouldn't it work with a classical for loop here?

Comment: @patrik i posted a solution with loops. I thought the same as you but it seems to me it is unneccessary complex compared with the other given solutions. Thats why i don't recommend it if there are so many build in methods you can use i.e. Luis and Adiels solutions.

Comment: @TheMinion you are right of course. However, the risk is that other people will have trouble following the code. What I was thinking, by the way was rather a solution like the one created by Adiel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is about as clear as your question :-)

```
x = [ 2016    2059    43
      2362    2450    88
      2450    2474    25
      2474    2684    36
      3301    3332    31 ];

[~, ii] = ismember(x(:,2),x(:,1));
jj = ~ii;
kk = sum(jj)+1+flipud(cumsum(flipud(-jj)));
ll = true(size(x,1),1);
ll(nonzeros(ii)) = false;
result = [ x(ll,1)  x(jj,2) accumarray(kk,x(:,3)) ];
```

This gives:

```
result =
        2016        2059          43
        2362        2684         149
        3301        3332          31
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your three vectors are A,B,C:

```
[com,ia,ib]=intersect(A,B);
A1=setdiff(A,com);
B1=setdiff(B,com);
C1=C;

for k=fliplr(1:length(ib))
      C1(ib(k)+1)=C1(ib(k))+C1(ib(k)+1);
      C1(ib(k))=[];
end
```

A1, B1, C1 are the result vectors

Comment: I am not sure this will work if there are multiple sets of connections, but that could probably be fixed. Beautiful, +1

Comment: Thanks. I've tried it, but not with very complicated cases. Anyway, seems that @Luis solution is faster...

Comment: Thanks a lot. im new in here and with matlab

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution with loops. Just checking for each value in `column 2` if it also appears in `column 1`. If so I add the values in `column 3` and replace the values as given in the example from the OP.
 The last 2 lines delete all now 0 values(those who have been replaced) and reshape `A` to the original form since the other comand returns `A` as a 1-dim-vector.

```
A = [2016    2059    43;
2362    2450    88;
2450    2474    25;
2474    2684    36;
3301    3332    31];


for k=1:5
   for l=2:1:5 
   if A(l,1)==A(k,2)
      A(l,3)= A(k,3)+A(l,3);
      A(l,1)= A(k,1);
      A(k,:) = 0;
      break
   end
   end
end
A=A(A~=0);
A=reshape(A,numel(A)/3,3);
```

Comment: Thanks guys. and sorry for my bad explanation :) Really Sorry. The solutions work and it is what i was looking for. I wanted to ask you this as well.

Comment: x = 2016    2059    43
2362    2450    88
2451    2474    25
2474    2684    36
3301    3332    31]
; here the difference from one data and another is one or zero. I would like to get  this [2016    2059    43
2362    2684    149
3301    3332    31]

Comment: @user3710685 So you want to enter an acceptance interval: If `My2ndColumn = My1stColumn +- Interval` do sth. Just play around with the `if`-argument. You could change it to `A(l,1)==A(k,2) || A(l,1)==A(k,2)+1` THis would check rather it is equal or 1 bigger as given in your example. But you could do sth like this if you want a real interval of acceptance: `A(l,1)<=A(k,2)+ Interval && A(l,1)>=A(k,2)-Interval` Then when setting `Interval=1` YOu would check rather it is equal plus minus 1. Otherwise just play around with the if-cases and logical operators. Type i.e. `help &&` for a list of them;)

Comment: Minion it gives me 3*n if i use more data but i would like n*3 when i reshape

Comment: @user3710685 you are right. fixed it i mixed up in the last line